# Congratulations, you're no longer in Beta!

Tags: discussion, beta

**This site started private beta before July 2012, so it is no longer "beta", it is a full site by our definition**. We've removed the word "beta" from your site banner because we believe that you aren't really a beta site any more, even if you don't get ten questions per day.

[image: Banner that reads "Congratulations" in three-dimensional white text with red, yellow and blue confetti.]

What this means for you:

- the "Beta" is removed from your banner
- the site is moved to the "[Launched](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched)" sites list on Area 51 - which will also remove the A51 info box from the right sidebar
- retain beta reputation levels
- full-site elections will be delayed but will be scheduled eventually

This is the start of a process that we are already discussing internally and will be bringing to the network for public discussion once the plan is finalized. My hope is that this will mean the end of the monolith we currently refer to as "Graduation" in favor of a well-defined set of small targets to achieve the various elements that made up "Graduation".

I'm sure you have many questions, please feel free to ask and I'll answer what I can. It helps me out a lot if you can limit answers to focus on a single question/subject rather than asking a dozen questions in one answer.

Please feel free to [follow the MSE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta) for more background on this decision. You can ask questions either here or there; I'll try to keep up with all of them. Your mods also have some info, so they may be answering in my stead.

Thanks so much for your patience and stay tuned!

Comment: Thank you!! I know this work has been a long time coming; I'm really glad we finally made it.

Comment: When do we get a proper logo?

Comment: @Zags I don't have an answer for you at the moment. We're already dealing with a backlog of sites waiting for designs from the graduations we've done since 2015 and we're still trying to decide when a site qualifies for a design moving forward. Leaving beta won't guarantee a design/logo.

Comment: @Zags: The comments to the same notice on [History](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3938/congratulations-youre-no-longer-in-beta) has some additional detail on the delays.

Comment: Related reading: [Is this our chance to “graduate”? Is this something we want?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1736/22373)

Comment: Related meta reading: [Experimenting with Pro Tempore elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/332286) also [Let's break up with “Graduation” and remove a bunch of “Beta” labels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303727/332286)

Comment: Is there an eta for other graduation benefits such as being able to migrate questions to another site?

Answer (score 11):

We won the longest beta award!

Can we have a gold beta badge now :P.

O wait, the longest road only adds 2 victory points.

Answer (score 9):

I am glad to see this as I am sure others are that this is happening not only for this site but for other long term beta sites that are part of the Stack Exchange Community. I am looking forward to when the backlog gets to our site and we can work on a new theme and everything else that comes with graduating from beta.

I also hope that initial graduation process and removal of the beta tag can help spur growth of the community and possibly lead to partnering with other websites that are part of the large board and card gaming community around the web.

As a side note I would like to thank the hard work of the moderators and all the community members for the hard work in maintaining this site. While I am not sure of the election process for moderators I hope that all of the current ones are asked to stay on as they have done an amazing job over the years!

A side question, outside elections when are we scheduled to get other graduation benefits such as being able to migrate questions to other sites?

Comment: "Full-site elections" implies that all the moderators would be elected. Current moderators could still decide to self-nominate and might be elected, of course. (That is, it'd be up to the community to ask us to stay on.)

Comment: @Cascabel Thank you for the clarification, I was under the impression that we would keep the current group (from those that wanted to stay on) and just elect new ones if more where needed.

Comment: Yeah, I know they did that for sites that were remaining in beta, but I think they were always called "pro tempore elections".